# Апплеты без public static void main

Tags: java

Знаю ,что апплеты создаються без `public static void main` а с помощью `public void init()`,тогда почему у меня выводит ошибка

```
Error: Main method not found in class com.company.Main, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

```
public class Main extends JApplet{

    private Formatter dateFmt=new Formatter();
    private Formatter time=new Formatter();
    public void init() {
        setSize(180, 100);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String era = "";
        if (c.get(Calendar.ERA) == 1) {
            era = "е.э";
            dateFmt.format("%A %td.%tm.%tY goda" + era, c, c, c, c);
            time.format("%T", c);

        }
    }
    public void  paint(Graphics g){

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawString("Апплет стартавал "+time,13,13);
        g.setColor(new Color(0,87,127));
        g.drawString(dateFmt.toString(),13,13);
    }
}
```

Comment: Именно. Вам нужно лишь вызвать этот метод из главного потока(который идет в методе `main`, который java не нашла).

Comment: Расскажите как Вы обращаетесь к апплету. Или как запускаете код.

Comment: обычно запускаю, нажимаю на run

Answer (score 1):

прежде всего хотел бы обратить Ваше внимание на то, что апплеты устарели и, если Вы изучаете этот вопрос с целью отличной от "палеонтологии" (поддержка древнего софта или праздное любопытство), рекомендую Вам остановиться и переосмыслить целесообразность дальнейшего изучения этой темы.

> The Applet API is deprecated, no replacement.

ответ на Ваш вопрос можно найти [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985712/how-do-i-run-an-applet-within-intellij-idea), где говорится, что апплеты не запускаются как обычные приложения через main, а имеют специальный интерфейс, через который можно будет запускать апплет из IDE если Вы установите соответсвующий плагин (например https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13148-java-applets-support)